# Obj-C combining strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

this must be such a simple problem but can someone tell me why this doesnt work:

```
visibilityString1 = @"the";
visibilityString2 = @"end";

visibilityString = (@"This is %@ %@", visibilityString1, visibilityString2);
```

Every time I try to combine strings this way, it will only return the second string so what I get is:

**end**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is:

```
visibilityString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is %@ %@", visibilityString1, visibilityString2];
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 6):

Use the following:

```
visibilityString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is %@ %@", visibilityString1, visibilittyString2];
```

**Explanations**

In C (and therefore also in ObjC), the syntax `(expression, expression, expression)` evaluates all expressions and returns the value of the last one. So if you do:

```
int foo = (bar(), baz(), 4);
```

`bar()` and `baz()` will be called, but `foo` will be `4`. (Don't do this at home. It's not a good practice.)